# How do I search and tally up a string "CTG" in another string which is a file?

Tags: java, string

How I do search for the string CTG from a file that is read as a string? And then give a count of how many times it shows up? 
For example, how would I add code to do this in here or anywhere in general:

```
public String readStrFromFile(){

    FileResource readFile = new FileResource();

    String DNA = readFile.asString();

    //System.out.println("DNA: " + DNA);

    return DNA;

}//end readStrFromFile() method;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expression

```
String DNA = readFile.asString();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("CTG");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(DNA);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group() + " at " + matcher.start());
}
```

Or if the file is so big, you should use KMP algorithm or similar.

**Edit :**
You can have a counter for it.

```
int count = 0; 
while(matcher.find()){
    count++;
    System.out.println(matcher.group() + " at " + matcher.start());
}
System.out.println("Number of count : " + count);
```

Comment: How would I go about counting all those CTGs? I need to know how many.

Comment: @TakaroSpike You can use counter for this.